# Show residuals with speedlm

Tags: r, lm

Due to the size of my dataset I'm bound to use [`Speedlm`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/speedglm/speedglm.pdf), [`fastLm`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppArmadillo/RcppArmadillo.pdf) or [`biglm`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/biglm/biglm.pdf). 
Unfortunately I'm stuck to using `speedlm` as `fastlm` doesn't have an `update` function, and `biglm` only supports single core.

Using speedlm I want to show all residuals. I know that for `lm` or `fastlm` I can simply use the `residuals()` function. However it turns out `speedlm` doesn't support this.

```
lmfit  <- speedglm(formula , res)
print(names(lmfit))
[1] "coefficients" "coef"         "df.residual"  "XTX"          "Xy"           "nobs"         "nvar"         "ok"           "A"            "RSS"          "rank"         "pivot"        "sparse"       "yy"           "X1X"          "intercept"    "method"       "terms"        "call"

lmfit <- fastLm(formula, res)
print(names(lmfit))
[1] "coefficients"  "stderr"        "df.residual"   "fitted.values" "residuals"     "call"          "intercept"     "formula"
```

**Is there a way to show all residuals using `speedlm`?**

When attempting to `print(residuals(lmfit))` it just prints a `NULL`

**Edit:**

When using the method mentioned by @Roland, it returns purely `NA`'s

```
lmfit  <- speedlm(formula , res, fitted=TRUE)
resids <- res$Daily_gain - predict(lmfit, newdata=res)
print(summary(resids))

# Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's
#   NA      NA      NA     NaN      NA      NA  829780
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
library(speedglm)
```

Store the fitted value (needs more RAM):

```
fit <- speedlm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris, fitted = TRUE)
iris$Sepal.Length - predict(fit)
```

Or don't store them (needs more CPU time):

```
fit1 <- speedlm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)
iris$Sepal.Length - predict(fit1, newdata = iris)
```

Comment: @ Roland, thanks it prints them now. However, storing them in RAM gets me the following warning: `Warning messages:
1: In predict.speedlm(rval, data) :
  prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading
2: In predict.speedlm(lmfit, newdata = res) :
  prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading` 
Should I just ignore this?

Comment: No, you should not ignore this.

Comment: @Roland What should I do with the warnings?

Comment: Investigate why you have a rank-deficient fit, of course.

Comment: @Roland I just continued with this code, and found it it purely returns NA values. while with other linear model functions it doesn't return a single `NA`. Any idea on why this can be?